# Google promotion tab

Tags: marketing-cloud, gmail

I am trying to get extra promotion buttons in Gmail.

The Salesforce documentation says that placing this code into an email

[Google Promotion Tab](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=mc_ceb_google_promotions_tab.htm&type=5)

will show some extra buttons in the promotion tab.

I'm not able to get this working. I manage to see the email in the promotion tab not I don't see any buttons.

I also tried pulling the code from a data extension but still the same.

- Is javascript even allowed to run in email context in SFMC ?

Answer (score 1):

Support is mentioning that the correct way of doing this is pulling the code from the Data Extension. Even if the code is right, it is up to Google to show it or not in Gmail. Not a Salesforce issue.